# Задание "Количество слов в тексте" (Python) - код занимается "приписками"

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества

Нужно определить, сколько различных слов содержится в тексте. При этом словом считается последовательность символов идущих подряд (за исключением пробелов), слова разделены одним или большим числом пробелов или символами конца строки. Например, "Share" и "Share," - это 2 разных слова.
Мой вариант:

```
inFile = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
a = str(inFile.readlines())
print(len(set(a.split())))
```

Тестовый текст:

```
She sells sea shells on the sea shore;
The shells that she sells are sea shells I'm sure.
So if she sells sea shells on the sea shore,
I'm sure that the shells are sea shore shells.
```

должно получиться 19 слов, а у меня зачем-то 20 ... где ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: Так посмотрите, что в set лежит

Comment: А посмотреть под отладкой? Вообще я не думаю что данный вопрос будет полезен будущим посетителям..

Comment: Просто выведите полученный сет на экран и посмотрите, что там за лишнее слово.

Comment: @Anamnian ну, это не вам решать, а будущим посетителям.

Comment: @MBo спасибо за подсказку! символ переноса строки нужно было убрать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прхожий вариант, но немного короче:

```
In [250]: len(set(open(r'C:\Temp\a.txt').read().split()))
Out[250]: 19
```

еще лучше будет воспользоваться `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

In [251]: len(set(Path(r'C:\Temp\a.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8').split()))
Out[251]: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Варианты ошибок: в конце файла перенос строки, пробелы, табуляция, смотреть надо исходники.
Мой вариант задачки, когда нужно отобрать слова как набор символов с хотя бы одной буквой (если надо, досыпьте в скобки русских буков, только Ёё не забудьте, ее нужно отдельно добавлять):

```
def word_conter(file_name: str) -> int:
    import re
    """
    Returns the number of words in a text file 
    or None in case of an error.
    Provided that the word is a sequence of characters 
    in which there is at least one letter
    """
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'rt') as f:
            s = (re.findall(
                r"\b(\w*[A-Za-z]+[!#$%&'\"*+-.^_`|~:\w]*)\b", f.read()))
        return len(s)
    except:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    # Pulls a file from the command line as a script run option.
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    print(word_conter(fname))
```